# How to select one mongodb database among many in atlas with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Sorry if my question is a bit dumb, but I really can't figure out how to use mongoose.
I have a sample database in atlas, which looks like this:
[image: sample database]

I have the following code in js:

```
const uri ="myurl";
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect(uri, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", function () {
  // here I dont know how to access one of the many databases and the collections inside the database
})
```

With mongodb it's clear, because MongoClient.connect returns a database object which gives access to any of the interested databases:

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  var sample_airbnb = db.db("sample_airbnb") // How can I access this in mongoose?
});
```

bellow is the full code:

```
const uri = "mongodb+srv://Alex:****@test0.ihhvy.mongodb.net/Test0?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
mongoose = require("mongoose"),
sc = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
}),
model = mongoose.model("listingsAndReviews", sc);

mongoose.connect(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }, () => {
     model.find((err, x) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(x);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will work.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect(uri, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", function () {
  const VendorSchema= new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    address: String
  });
  const Vendor = mongoose.model('Vendor', VendorSchema);
  const vendorOne = new Vender({ name: 'John Doe', address: 'Some Street, New York, NY' });
  vendorOne.save(function (err, vendor) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('success');
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I'm still unable to access my data. I'm trying access the name field inside the listingsAndReviews collection inside sample_airbnb database inside my atlas database.
```const sc = new mongoose.Schema({
    
name: String,

  }),

  model = mongoose.model("sample_airbnb", sc);

mongoose.connect(

  uri,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  },

  () => {

    model.find((err, x) => {

      if (err) throw err;

      console.log(x);

    });

  }

);

```

Comment: Does the conosle.log run?

Comment: I receive an empty array from the console

Comment: Your credentials are not set or wrong.  r_dmr answer will fix it.

Comment: It's not that because without mongoose and with the same credentials it works. I think the main issue is the model. I'm not sure what the first parameter should be. 
I tried "mongoose.model('sample_airbnb.listingsAndReviews', sc)", "mongoose.model('sample_airbnb', sc)", and "mongoose.model('listingsAndReviews', sc)".
So the structure is as following:
I have a database in atlas. Inside, I have 8 databases. the first one, sample_airbnb has many collections. I want to access the field "name". 
The documentation states that I'm supposed to use the collection name, but I'm not specifying the db

Comment: You'r not connecting successfully because the success callback isn't running. Can you post the complete code for this,  that may help.

Comment: const uri = "mongodb+srv://Alex:****@test0.ihhvy.mongodb.net/Test0?retryWrites=true&w=majority",

mongoose = require("mongoose"),

sc = new mongoose.Schema({

    name: String,

}),

model = mongoose.model("listingsAndReviews", sc);


mongoose.connect(uri, {

    useNewUrlParser: true,

    useUnifiedTopology: true,

  }, () => {

     model.find((err, x) => {

      if (err) throw err;

      console.log(x);

    });

})

Comment: reading that comment will probably make my head hurt. take a look at my answer, i updated it.

Comment: checkout this repo, it may help you get a better understanding of the mongoose flow. https://github.com/kap1147/jwt-auth-server

Answer (score 2):

When connecting to mongodb via mongoose, if your mongodb uri doesn't contain any database name then it will connect to **test** database. So you have to define your database name at the end of the mongodb connection uri and it will connect to that defined database.
Normally, the database connection uri has the structure like:

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<cluster>/<your_desired_database>
```

so you should add your database name after a */* at the end of the uri